# R. Run lm function over list of many dataframes in directory. Error: invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'

Tags: r, list, lapply, lm

I have a directory with 1,200,000 .txt files (data frames). All files have the same column names (ID SEX PV YPV APV GT N E Y M C A). Using R, I create a list of all elements within this directory:

```
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("broom") 
library("tidyr")

snp_list <- list.files(pattern=".txt", all.files = T,full.names = F)
```

I want to apply a function over each element in the list:

```
pv1= lapply(snp_list, function(x) tidy(lm(PV ~ GT*SEX + M + GT*N,x)))
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character' 
9.eval(predvars, data, env) 
8.model.frame.default(formula = PV ~ GT * SEX + M + GT * N, data = x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) 
7.stats::model.frame(formula = PV ~ GT * SEX + M + GT * N, data = x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) 
6.eval(mf, parent.frame()) 
5.eval(mf, parent.frame()) 
4.lm(PV ~ GT * SEX + M + GT * N, x) 
3.tidy(lm(PV ~ GT * SEX + M + GT * N, x)) 
2.FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.lapply(snp_list, function(x) tidy(lm(PV ~ GT * SEX + M + GT * N, x)))
```

Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snp_list` is just vector of filenames, you need to read the data.

```
library(broom) 
pv1= lapply(snp_list, function(x) tidy(lm(PV ~ GT*SEX + M + GT*N,read.table(x))))
```

You might need to add additional arguments to `read.table` based on your data.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah !. When I run: "snp_list <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", all.files = T,full.names = F) --> pv1= lapply(snp_list, function(x) tidy(lm(PV ~ GT*SEX + M + GT*N,read.table(x)))) " I get: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'PV' not found

Comment: Step 1 check what is the right way to read your data. Does `df <- read.table(snp_list[1])` work? If not then check the separator in your data.